# zsh script not emitting expected enable/disable output

Tags: macos, shell, zsh

I've got this following bash script, in witch for every user loggend in a mac i will check if the secure token status is set to enabled.
Then I will count, with grep -ic command, how many time the word enable is present.
Then, if the word enable is not equal to 0 I will print the username and the word enabled otherwise disable.
This is the output i've got:

```
luigiMac
martaMac
provamacmarco:Disabled
```

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

result=""
enabled="Enabled"
disabled="Disabled"
users=$(dscl . -list /Users | grep -v -e '_' -e root -e nobody -e daemon)

for item_ in "${users[@]}"; do
    newUsers+=("$item_")
    #echo $newUsers
done

for i in "${newUsers[@]}";do
#echo $i[4]
tokenStatus+=$(sysadminctl -adminUser "" -adminPassword "" -secureTokenStatus "$i" 2>&1 | grep -ic "enabled")
print $tokenStatus
if [[ "${tokenStatus[@]}" -ne 0 ]]
then
result="${i}:${enabled}"
echo "${result}"
else
result="${i}:${disabled}"
echo "${result}"
fi
done

#echo "${result}"
```

I don't understand why the script doesn't print enable or disable for the other username.

Comment: your shebang is `zsh` but you're claiming that you're using `bash`. which one is correct?

Comment: sorry, you're right, the correct is zsh

Comment: `users` is not an array; it' just a single string with embedded linefeeds.

Comment: Aside from what chepner correctly said, `newUsers` is also not an array, but just a string. However it is used in the loop as if it were an array. I think the whole script deserves careful debugging line-by-line. Try to run it with `set -x` turned on and fix all the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no `zsh` expert but IMO you're doing a lot of unnecessary things in your script; you could simplify it a little bit with:

```bash
dscl . -list /Users |
grep -vE -e '^_' -e '^(root|daemon|nobody)$' |
while IFS=$'\n' read -r user
do
    if sysadminctl ... -secureTokenStatus "$user" 2>&1 |
       grep -q 'ENABLED'
    then
        result=Enabled
    else
        result=Disabled
    fi
    printf '%s:%s\n' "$user" "$result"
done
```